# Getting ModuleNotFoundError when calling a bokeh server

Tags: python, module, server, pycharm, bokeh

I have a PyCharm project where I created a package, having name `my_package`, with a proper `__init__.py`. In the same folder, I have a bokeh server application `webapp.py`. This file contains `import my_package`.

When I want to call

```
bokeh serve webapp.py
```

I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'
```

I suppose that this may be a naive mistake that does not have to do anything with bokeh.

Thank you for any help.